# Can I do merges with the TFS offline?

Tags: tfs, merge, repository

We are having a problem with the TFS connection. Is there any way to do merges between branchs with the TFS down?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so since TFS merges items by comparing the items from the source/target branch which at least one would be on the server.

Comment: Correct, TFS merge is computed by the server using merge history.

Answer (score 1):

It would make no sense to do so. If your TFS is offline, you cannot know whether you would merge the newest source code state. This would be highly insecure since it leads to code missmatch.

If you want to merge some code offline, do it manually with tools like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) and update it to your TFS when its online again ;)